# « Se mêler de » : Comment l'interpréter correctement ?

Tags: sens, expressions

Comment dois-je interpréter correctement la question suivante ?

> Les banques centrales face aux crises passées et à venir : de quoi se mêlent-t-elles ?

Je pense que la meilleure façon de l'interpréter, c'est comme si elle demandait «The central banques in face of past crisis and future ones: why do they intervene?» Est-ce que j'ai raison?

Merci.

P.S.: Please, feel free correct the errors in my text. Thanks ;)

Comment: Translating from French to English is twice off topic here. Here is how I would do it anyway "Central Banks in front of past and future crisis, what business is it of them ?"

Comment: @jlliagre Ok. but then, why the tag "traduction"?

Comment: The *traduction* tag is for questions asking for the French equivalent of another language (than French) expression. You are not referring to any specific expression in your sentence, moreover, the source language is not a non French language and the target language is not French. If you have trouble to understand some part or all of the original sentence, state which ones. If you have trouble to express something in English, this is the wrong site. Have a look to http://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: To add to @jlliagre's comment I'd say that questions asking for a translation into French are also off topic if they can be answered by consulting a dictionary. Which isn't the case with your question.

Comment: In order to **improve your question** you should identify what words or phrases you're having difficulty understanding, @Random did a good edit to legitimate your question (and Stéphane Gimenez removing the "traduction" tag), but your point of concern might be elsewhere. Sentence structure?  What a pronoun refers to?   It's also a good idea to give the context where you have seen the sentence. Here, stating it's a headline and giving link might be a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Les banques centrales face aux crises passées et à venir : de quoi se mêlent -t-elles ?

Est le titre annonçant un débat radiophonique, on applique les mêmes règles que pour construire un titre de presse. Les titres ont souvent des structures particulières, même si c'est moins frappant en français qu'en anglais. Un titre doit être le plus concis possible, doit accrocher et interpeller le lecteur/auditeur pour lui donner envie de lire/d'écouter la suite.

> Les banques centrales face aux crises passées et à venir

: l'auteur de l'article expose le sujet du débat, pas de verbe parce qu'il faut faire court, pas de mot dont la présence est implicite pour le lecteur.

- (Comment se comportent) les banques centrales (quand elles sont) face aux crises

et il s'agit des crises qui ont déjà eu lieu : **passées**, et des crises qui vont avoir lieu : **à venir**.

Les deux points de ponctuation « : » introduisent la deuxième partie du titre, ils servent à restreindre le sujet, on pourrait aussi avoir une virgule ou un tiret.

> de quoi se mêlent-t-elles ?

: le choix du verbe « se mêler » n'est pas anodin. L'auteur du titre n'a pas écrit «  de quoi s'occupent-elles ? » (*deal with*) ni « en quoi interviennent-elles ? » (*intervene*) mais « de quoi se **mêlent-elles** » (*meddle with*) : le titre  annonce le ton du débat, on nous dit que les banques s'occupent de choses qui ne les regardent pas / dont elles ne devraient pas s'occuper, le lecteur est interpellé, il s'attend à une polémique et peut-être bien à des révélations, ce qui est très « payant » en termes d'audience pour la presse.
Et l'impact de l'idée est d'autant plus fort qu'elle est placée en fin de phrase.

À comparer avec le titre réduit à sa banalité :

> Les banques centrales s'occupent de ce qui ne les regarde pas quand elles sont face aux crises passées et à venir.

Comment: Merci beaucoup pour ta réponse merveilleuse. Elle est très complète.  +1 ;)

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. Peut-être « trop » complète mais tant mieux si ça t'a aidé à comprendre. Il faudra que tu essaies de mieux identifier les points qui te posent problème dans tes questions futures. J'ai essayé de te donner quelques pistes sous ta question.

Comment: Oui, je les ai lu. Je comprends maintenant. Mon problème était avec l'expression  'de quoi se mêlent-t-ils?'. à la prochaine fois je serais plus précis. ;)

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. Then can you please improve the translation I suggested in my first comment to your question: "What business is it of them ?" as I thought it was precisely conveying the French meaning but it looks like it wasn't?

Comment: @jlliagre I expect it's "what business is it of **theirs**"  (or "what business do they have") and conveys the same meaning to my mind. But "facing past and future crisis" would probably be better here (I would not use "in face of" either). But as you said it's a question for ELL!

Comment: @Laure Yes, "theirs" of course. Thanks !